# How to join a DataTable and a SQL table using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need to join a `DataTable` and a SQL table using LINQ.

This is the LINQ query:

```
from c in db.Staging
join c1 in tagging on c.RPT_ID equals c1.RPT_ID
select c
```

However I am getting the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if all of the records that you're joining on are in memory first. You'll need to do the following.

```
var s = db.Staging.ToList(); 
var joinedResult = from c in s
                 join c1 in tagging on c.RPT_ID = c1.RPT_ID
                 select c;
```

Calling ToList() causes the SQL to execute and fetch all the records from the database. This isn't good if you have lots of records in the database.

What you probably want to do is the following actually.

```
var IDs = tagging.Select(t=>t.RPT_ID).ToArray();
var matches = db.Staging.Where(s=>IDs.Contains(s.RPT_ID);
```

That will only find the Staging records in the DB that you have IDs for in your data table. Much more efficient if you have a big Staging table.

Comment: Can you please share the syntax in vb.net for second option

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from c in db.Staging
join c1 in tagging on c.RPT_ID = c1.RPT_ID
select c
```

I don't have VS to confirm but I think it's breaking on the 'equals' since it's a built in .NET function. LINQ can't translate all functions to TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
db = new YourContext();
MyClass t = new MyClass ();
var listOfIEnumerableData = from myClass in t.GetMyClassData()
                            select new MyClass { ID = myClass.ID, Name=myClass.Name,Description=myClass.Description};

var v = (from t1 in db.DbClass.AsEnumerable()
         join t2 in listOfIEnumerableData on t1.DbClassFK equals t2.ID
         select new VmMyClass
             {
                 MyClass = t1,
                 DbClass = t2
             }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Acc_Chart1.ID).Take(100).AsEnumerable();

this.DataList = v;
```

Comment: This Code is fully workable. to join SQL table with IEnumerable Collection

Comment: I Have this Collection,public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetMyClassData()
        {
            List<MyClass> lst= new List<MyClass>();
            MyClass a= new MyClass
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "ASSETS",
                Description= "Assets Info"
            };
            MyClass l= new MyClass
            {
                ID = 2,
                Name = "LIABILITIES",
                DrIncrease = "Liabilities"
            };
            lst.Add(a);
            lst.Add(l);
            return lst;
        }, and A Sql Table Name DbClass,To Join

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42622821/edit) your answer to further code. I would explain however what your code _does_

Comment: Dear Bugs, This code Select data from two table, One table is Located in SQL Server and another table located in your own Solution as List or IEnumerable Collection,